# What is the number of subgroups in $\mathbb{Z}_{60} \times \mathbb{Z}_{45} \times \mathbb{Z}_{12} \times \mathbb{Z}_{36}$ of order $2$ and index $2$?

Tags: group-theory

This is exercise 9, page 166, Dummit and Foote, Abstract Algebra.

*Given $A = \mathbb{Z}_{60} \times \mathbb{Z}_{45} \times \mathbb{Z}_{12} \times \mathbb{Z}_{36}$  determine the number of subgroups of order $2$.*

I wrote $A$ in its invariant factor decomposition form: $A = \mathbb{Z}_{180} \times \mathbb{Z}_{180} \times \mathbb{Z}_{12} \times  \mathbb{Z}_3$. In other words $A$ is of type $(180,180,12,3)$. There is exactly one element of order $2$ in each of the first three factors composing $A$.  There is no element of order $2$ in $\mathbb{Z}_3$.  So the elements of order $2$ in $A$ are of the form $(a,b,c,1)$ where $a,b,c$ can be the identity or the element of order $2$ in the first three factors of $A$.  However we must exclude the case $(1,1,1,1)$.  So I think the answer is $7$.

I do not know how to find the second part of the question:  What is the number of subgroups of index $2$.  If it helps I have found that A expressed in its elementary divisor decomposition is the direct product of cyclic groups of order $4,4,4,3,3,9,9,5,5$.

Comment: I don't think that you have the right invariant factor decomposition. Shouldn't every prime factor appear in the smallest invariant factor?

Comment: I double checked my invariant factor decomposition.  I think it is correct?  There is an algorithm to compute this decomposition that is much simpler to perform than to explain.  What do you think the invariant factor decomposition should be?

Comment: You're correct, sorry

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: try writing $$A=\mathbb{Z}_4^3\times\mathbb{Z}_3^2\times\mathbb{Z}_5^2\times\mathbb{Z}_9^2$$ and ask the same question about groups of index $2$ in $\mathbb{Z}_4^3$.

Comment: I asked myself "the same question about groups of index 2 in Z_4^3" but I didn't get an answer.  I have memorized the definition of index:  If H is a subgroup of G then the index is the number of cosets of H in G.  In other words, |G|/|H| is the index of H in G.  So we are trying to find the number of subgroups of order  583200 ?

Comment: It will be easier to think about finding groups of order $32$ within $\mathbb{Z}_4^3$, and then cross them with $\mathbb{Z}_3^2\times\mathbb{Z}_5^2\times\mathbb{Z}_9^2$. $\mathbb{Z}_4^3$ only has $64$ elements, and it's reasonable to work out its subgroup lattice.

Comment: OK.  I think there are 3 subgroups of Z_4^3 with order 32.     Z_4 X Z_4 X Z_2  and   Z_4 X Z_2 X Z_4,  and   Z_2 X Z_4 X Z_4.    I do not understand how this will help in counting the number of subgroups of index 2 in  Z_60 X Z_45 X Z_12 X Z_36?  Is it implicit in the exercise that we are to count the number of NONISOMORPHIC subgroups of index 2?

Comment: If you take a subgroup of index $2$ in $A$, you can project it onto these subgroups of the form $\mathbb{Z}_{p^m}^n$. The index of the image in $\mathbb{Z}_{p^m}^n$ has to divide $2$. So for the subgroups with $p\neq2$, the image has to be the whole $\mathbb{Z}_{p^m}^n$. Therefore if $B$ is a subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}_{4}^3$ of index $2$, then $B\times\mathbb{Z}_{3}^2\times\mathbb{Z}_{5}^2\times\mathbb{Z}_{9}^2$ is a subgorup of $A$ of index $2$.

Comment: In fact I think what I just said could be applied to the original four factor groups, three of which have a unique subgroup of index $2$, and one of which has none.

Comment: So there are exactly 3 subgroups in A that have index 2: Z_30 X Z_45 X Z_12 X Z_36,   Z_60 X Z_45 X Z_6 X Z_36,   Z_60 X Z_45 X Z_12 X Z_18.  ?

Comment: Yes. But I'd call them $2\mathbb{Z}_{60}\times\mathbb{Z}_{45}\times\mathbb{Z}_{12}\times\mathbb{Z}_{36}$, $\mathbb{Z}_{60}\times\mathbb{Z}_{45}\times2\mathbb{Z}_{12}\times\mathbb{Z}_{36}$, and $\mathbb{Z}_{60}\times\mathbb{Z}_{45}\times\mathbb{Z}_{12}\times2\mathbb{Z}_{36}$.

Comment: Yes, I understand.  Thank you.